# downloading audio using ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

**I am downloading audio using ASIHTTPRequest, when I check destination folder, there is no audio file there.** Here is sample code.

naking destination Path in viewdidLoad

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Rabana"];
```

Here is the Download audio function using ASIHTTPREQUEST and making Queue :**

```
- (IBAction)DownloadOneFile:(UIButton *)sender {
if (!networkQueue) {
    networkQueue = [[ASINetworkQueue alloc] init];
}
[networkQueue reset];
networkQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount=1;
[networkQueue setDownloadProgressDelegate:_ProgressView];
networkQueue.shouldCancelAllRequestsOnFailure=NO;
[networkQueue setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(AudioFetchComplete:)];
[networkQueue setRequestDidFailSelector:@selector(AudioFetchFailed:)];
[networkQueue setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
[networkQueue setDelegate:self];

ASIHTTPRequest *request;
request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://appstabs.com/wahab_audios_files/1.mp3"]];[request setDownloadDestinationPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dataPath]];
[request setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-part",dataPath]];
request.shouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground=YES;
[request setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
request.allowResumeForFileDownloads=YES;
[networkQueue addOperation:request];
[networkQueue go];
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.0
                                              target: self
                                            selector:@selector(onTick)
                                            userInfo: nil repeats:YES];
```

}
- (void)AudioFetchComplete:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/",dataPath] ofType:@"mp3"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error: &error];
audioPlayer.delegate=self;
audioPlayer.volume = 1;
[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
```

}

**But i am getting nil in "path" string and and my Audio player is not intialized.**

Comment: "Rabana" is your subdirectory?

Comment: Yes.i am making sub directory and saving all audio in it

Comment: Then check my answer. And try it. In your code I did not saw subdirectiry creation code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to save in "Rabana" subdirectory but you not created subdirectory

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Rabana"];
NSError *error;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
```

And In place of this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/",dataPath] ofType:@"mp3"];
```

ues this:

```
NSString *path =    [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:YOUR_FILE_NAME];
```

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'  ,          

App is crashing , still geting nil in path

Comment: i did the same what u said

   NSString *path = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.mp3"];
but when i play audio in PLAY button , NO audio there.


    
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error: &error];
    audioPlayer.delegate=self;
    audioPlayer.volume = 1;
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

Comment: the prob is how to access my Downloaded "1.mp3" audio file ?
is my audio file is downloading ?
how to check it? thanks

Comment: did your file is downloades successfully or not? If file is exist please see what is the file name, then try to access it.

Comment: YES, file download successfully , setRequestDidFinishSelector called successfully.
File exit on mention server with name 1.mp3

Comment: Check once to downlaoded path. Go to document->Rabana folder. And check there.

Comment: creating a document named "Rabana" having size 105KB equal to size of my 1.mp3 file. but inside it no file there.

Comment: @Mujahid please try to debug your code. And see where is the actual problem. Your code after correction should work.